# VB.net: in a dll temporarily grant time to react on a form event

Tags: vb.net, forms, dll

In a Windows forms application, I start a longer synchronisation. The synchronisation code is handled by a dll. In case the connection to the server breaks, the synchronisation can't be continued and I display a cancel checkbox in the form (by raising an event in the dll that triggers an event procedure in the form), while the dll tries to reestablish the connection in a loop.

In the dll:

```
Public Event Conn_Lost(ByVal sender As Object)
```

In the form:

```
...
AddHandler myDLL.Conn_Lost, AddressOf Synch_Conn_Lost
...

Public Function Synch_Conn_Lost() As Boolean
  ' code to make checkbox visible
End Function
```

It is the responsibility of the user to stop that loop. But when I click the checkbox, the corresponding event procedure in the form isn't called, and the dll simply continues with its code.

My question: is there a way the dll can allow the user to check the checkbox in the form? I.e. give the control temporarily back to the form? Or maybe I should structure the program differently? Thanks!

Comment: Would you please show the eventhandler routine? Note that the event is triggered in the form containing the control, not in the dll.

Comment: The event raised in the dll works: the checkbox in the form is displayed correctly. My problem is that I don't know how to be able to click on the checkbox. There simply nothing is happening, because the code in the dll runs in a loop trying to reestablsich the connection to the server.

Comment: Show us the code or we can't help.

Comment: I updated my question. But as I said: that code is not the problem, I think. I simply don't know how to be able to click the checkbox in the form when dll code is running.

Comment: Does the DLL code run in the same thread as the form, i.e. the UI thread? If the form is frozen and doesn't respond to actions/clicks then that might be the case. Can we see the event handler for the check box as well as how you add it?

Comment: I suspect that's the case. The form is busy and can't accept interaction. You should call the loop in a separate thread to allow user interaction in the form.

Comment: You can run the loop from the dll on a background worker or on a separate thread which would enable interaction with the main form while the loop is running .

Comment: all: thank you for your thoughts. @Visual Vincent gave the essential hint. I didn't find a way to implement it, though (really don't understand the whole threading-thing enough). So I restructured the program so that the code in the dll throws an error and goes back to the calling form where the error is handled properly.